# Esiste una traduzione per il termine musicale inglese "to strum"?

Tags: translation

Sto scrivendo un manuale di chitarra, e con l'obiettivo di evitare anglicismi inutili ho il seguente problema: abbiamo un termine in italiano per indicare **l'atto di suonare tutte le corde di una chitarra assieme**, sia con la mano che con il plettro, in inglese *to strum*? Fonti online lo rendono con *strimpellare*, che è un termine peggiorativo. In spagnolo esiste *rasgueo*/*rasguear* ad esempio.

Per chi non avesse chiaro, [la chitarra di Wonderwall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bx1Bh8ZvH84) è un celebre esempio di strumming.

Perifrasi come *suonare un accordo* non sono precise, perché gli accordi possono essere anche pizzicati.

Non voglio proprio usare *strummare*, aiutatemi :))

EDIT: credo proprio che userò *pennare*/*pennata* come suggerito nei commenti, almeno finché non inventerò un neologismo pertinente.

Comment: Non sono un esperto, ma potrebbe andare il termine pennare, cioè l'atto di effettuare una pennata?

Comment: @abarisone fuochino, pennata va già meglio grazie ^^ solo che si può _pennare_ anche senza penna (o plettro che sia), vediamo se arrivano altre idee.

Comment: Wordreference suggerisce *schitarrare* ma visto l'altro significato del termine (suonare male la chitarra!) non mi sento di scriverlo come risposta senza la conferma di un chitarrista...

Comment: Per non temere dire l'obvio, il termine spagnolo *rasguear* mi ricorda l'italiano *raschiare*, "to scrape or grate". Potrebbe dare più validità all'argomento che siano entrambi peggiorativi o almeno ironici.

Comment: @Rickmakeitquick: Non penso che "rasguear" in spagnolo sia percepito come peggiorativo.

Answer (score 2):

The english definition suggests that:

> ***[To strum](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/strum)*** is to play a guitar or another stringed instrument by brushing the strings with your fingers. ***It's pretty easy to strum a ukulele, but it sounds better if you know some chords.***
>
> You might tell the guitar player in your band, "Strum a few chords of that song we wrote yesterday." ***You can also strum idly on your sister's banjo without playing actual chords, just by running your thumb down the strings.***  Strum is a noun, too, meaning "the sound or act of strumming." This word dates from the 18th century, and experts think it's imitative, sounding a bit like an actual strum. (Vocabulary.com)

All [dictionaries](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=LrEWW-jhE8iIgAbKxLz4DQ&q=strum%20traduzione%20&oq=strum%20traduzione%20&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..0i22i30l2j33i160.2273.6955..7252...1....151.1943.7j12......0....1.........0j41j0i22i10i30j0i70j0i10j0i67j0i131i67j0i70i255.P9CqOFNZl2I%3D) suggest  “strimpellare” as a literal translation of the term which, unlike the English term, conveys a more “derogatory” connotation. According to the above definition to “strum” can be used both ways, but it certainly conveys a  more neutral connotation.

My take is that there is no perfect literal  translation, as suggested also in the following [extract](http://www.chitarradaspiaggia.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2658):

> VERSIONE RITMICA "***STRUMMING***":
>
> - Serve a scandire il ritmo e la velocità del canto, e valorizza al massimo le armonie. Si suona eseguendo accordi completi, parziali e a singole note accompagnando il canto. È tipica dei "Chitarristi da Spiaggia". Immaginando ogni corda come una voce che canta, è come se suonasse un coro di voci.
>
> Vantaggi: si sente in maniera estremamente chiara sia la ritmica che le armonie.
>
> Svantaggi: dal punto di vista armonico, la modalità "strumming" è approssimata.
>
> Chitarrista di riferimento: Luciano Ligabue.
>
> Esempio di video: "Cosa vuoi che sia" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tc_zAS4sFUk

Comment: Gio, rispondi in inglese quando scrivono in italiano, adesso? :D

Comment: @DaG - la domanda partiva da un termine e la sua definizione in inglese ... poi il resto mi venuto così :).